# Kepler problem, How can I prove that the period of elliptic orbit is only dependent on energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

We are also given the following hint:

> Equate the energies and sectorial velocities at the apogee and perigee of an elliptic orbit to express the area of the ellipse in terms of E.

For some background info:

Energy is: $E = \frac{-GMm}{2a}$ where m is the mass of satellite, M is mass of object in center, a is the semi major axis of elliptic orbit.

Period is: $T=2\pi\sqrt\frac{a^3}{\mu}$ where $\mu$ is gravitational constant.

And sectorial velocity of an ellipse is:
$\frac{L}{2m}$ where $L$ is angular velocity

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi it’s still the semi major axis

Comment: I think there will be heavy usage of orbital mechanics considering the energy given is at an intermediate point between semi major and semi minor axis. I would request a migration on PhySE

Comment: Can't you just eliminate $a$ between the two equations?

Comment: @KeithMcClary what will you do post elimination? we need area of ellipse=πab , we know b using the eccentricity relation

Comment: It follows from the equations you have written that $T=2\pi\left((-GMm/(2E))^3/\mu \right)^{1/2}$. So this proves the period only depends on $E$. Do you have a question about how to derive the formulas for energy or period?

Comment: Given that the hint talks about the area of the ellipse and we are also given the sectoral velocity, I think the intention of this question should be to derive the formula for $T$ rather than treat it as known.